# Cant Access to OpenWrt via LuCI or SSH

Tags: configuration, gateway, openwrt, dhcp, luci

I have a TP-Link TL-WR741ND with OpenWrt installed.
My IP to access LuCI is 10.0.0.1
I was trying to config a Gateway for an interface and a DHCP server using LuCI but accidentally I set the gateway ip to the same ip to access via LuCI (10.0.0.1).

I tried to access to the WebUI with the browser but it throws a timeout.
I also tried logging in via SSH using PuTTY (it also throws a timeout).

```html
root@10.0.0.1
```

How can I reset my router config or revert the changes I did?

Comment: Did you already try holding the reset button for 5 seconds?  That should restore defaults.

Comment: A lot of times, it's a very old and simple hardware model, so it was impossible to fix